# Transportation from Kuala Lumpur Airport to Port Dickson

Tags: airport-transfer, taxis, malaysia, kul

I will spend my weekend in Port Dickson and I have already booked my plane ticket to Kuala Lumpur. However I'm still wonder how to go to Port Dickson from the airport.

Here are my questions :

1) It seems I can take a taxi from the Airport. Is there any preffered taxi (like in Indonesia, we have Blue Bird Group Taxi, which is safer than other kind of taxi)

2) How much is the taxi fare roughly?

3) Any safety tips and tricks for choosing taxi in Malaysia?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure why you pick Port Dickson, it's not really a favourable travel destination any more afaik.

About the taxi, you should be able to get it from the airport. go to the official taxi counter and buy the taxi voucher from there only (**not from anywhere or anyone else**), this should be the safest way. The fare should be less than RM 150 (estimation based on the distance. it was RM 70 in 2008 according to [this](http://www.tripadvisor.com.my/ShowTopic-g293951-i7006-k1488553-KLIA_to_Port_Dickson-Malaysia.html))

**If you are in the town area (not in the airport)**, my personal preferred taxi operator will be [Sunlight](http://www.sunlighttaxi.com/), but any taxi should do if you are still in KL area. Just remember to demand the driver to use meter, unless there is a ticket counter.

So, wish you a safe and pleasant trip.

Comment: To be a bit clearer: A single company has a monopoly on taxis at the airport, and you have to pay up front at a counter so there's no risk of getting ripped off.  (Or, rather, the risk is 100% since the fixed fares are high...)  There are also touts wandering around trying to guide you to unofficial taxis, but these are technically not allowed and entirely unregulated.

Comment: @jpatokal, I updated the answer. Hope it's clearer now. Thanks.

Comment: What happened to Port Dickson (or how has it been before). I think one more thing to add about overland travel: last time, only blue cars (which you can only find at special locations, like the bus terminal) are allowed to travel in between cities.